# Why does GDB/OpenOCD only stop on a breakpoint every second time I run the debug config?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, debugging, gdb, openocd

It seems to be some memory issue that I'm dealing with, when I monitor the openOCD logs, and execute the first time, output looks like

```
[OpenOCD]
Info : [esp32.cpu0] Target halted, PC=0x400D4B37, debug_reason=00000001
[OpenOCD]
Info : [esp32.cpu1] Target halted, PC=0x400E4256, debug_reason=00000000
...
...
...
shutdown command invoked
Info : dropped 'gdb' connection
[OpenOCD]
[Stopped] : OpenOCD Server
```

and when I re-execute,

```
[OpenOCD]
Info : [esp32.cpu0] Target halted, PC=0x40000400, debug_reason=00000000
[OpenOCD]
Info : [esp32.cpu1] Target halted, PC=0x40000400, debug_reason=00000000
...
...
...
Info : [esp32.cpu0] Target halted, PC=0x400D4B34, debug_reason=00000001
[OpenOCD]
Info : Set GDB target to 'esp32.cpu0'
[OpenOCD]
Info : [esp32.cpu1] Target halted, PC=0x400E4256, debug_reason=00000000
[OpenOCD]
Info : [esp32.cpu0] Target halted, PC=0x400D4B37, debug_reason=00000001
[OpenOCD]
Info : Set GDB target to 'esp32.cpu0'
[OpenOCD]
Info : [esp32.cpu1] Target halted, PC=0x400E4256, debug_reason=00000000
```

(showing only diff for brevity). Notice the difference in `PC` and `debug_reason` between the runs.

Environment:

- VSCode 1.7.5
- VSCode [launch.json](https://gist.github.com/parksj10/1c065850270d4c0c3bc2abcb56eac72b)
- ESP32 Pico Devkit v4.1
- ESP Prog JTAG debugger
- ESP-IDF 4.4.3
- [ESP-IDF VSCode Settings](https://gist.github.com/parksj10/4fb758ba6391ce4d1344e064d5f1345b)
- [`hello_world_main.c`](https://gist.github.com/parksj10/19295434fd313956da6ec70d0bd59806)

Comment: Please read [ask]'s section on helping others reproduce the problem (I'm looking at your gist link).

Comment: @user I was trying to condense it to a digestible amount of information, but I've added all the details as request...